# Whats the best way to deploy a chrome extension to your in house orginaization?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to deploy some in house software along with an extension, e.g. a native messaging app. 
Based on this page: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions
It doesn't look like you can install from an external .crx anymore.

I've used the master_preferences file before:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453
But that only works with new installs & I need to deploy to my existing users who are already setup with Chrome.

So is my only options to publish to the Web Store & have my users click on an Inline Installation link?

Comment: SO doesn't really like "the best way to" questions, but this is really more of a "can I do this at all", which is different.  It's definitely related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/35637278/2336725, which was asked shortly after yours.

Comment: I posted an answer to [SO-35637278](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637278/offline-google-chrome-extensions). You can still install external extensions but you will need a Google Chrome for business.